# Instantiate an object and translate it randomly

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, debugging

My goal through this code in C # is that each time the player presses the <kbd>Q</kbd> I create a cube at a fixed position given by another object, then begin translating it in a random direction. ie.

- first press: a cube is created at the spawn point and moves away in direction 1
- second press: a cube is created at the spawn point and moves away in direction 2
- third press: a cube is created at the spawn point and moves away in direction 3

I don't understand why the code below does not work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class spawn_random_trajet : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Spawn, Spawn2;
    public Transform origineSpawn;
    public float moveSpeed=5f;

    void Update () {    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {    
            int random_trajet_x = Random.Range (-10,10);
            int random_trajet_y = Random.Range (-10,10);
            int random_trajet_z = Random.Range (-10,10);

            Spawn2 = Instantiate(
                 Spawn, 
                 origineSpawn.position, 
                 origineSpawn.rotation
            ) as GameObject;

            transform.Translate ( 
                 random_trajet_x*Time.deltaTime*moveSpeed,
                 random_trajet_y*Time.deltaTime*moveSpeed,
                 random_trajet_z*Time.deltaTime*moveSpeed
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 1):

`transform.Translate` says "move **me** by this offset **now**"

It does **not** say "take *the object I just spawned*, and start moving it at this velocity, *every frame* from now into the indefinite future"

Really, you should put the movement behaviour on the object you've spawned, not on the object that spawns it, [as I described to you in a previous answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/170181/39518).

```
public class TranslateOverTime : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, -1);

    void Update() {
        transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

Place an instance of this TranslateOverTime script on the prefab object you wish to instantiate.

```
public class CreateMovingObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public TranslateOverTime prefab;
    public Transform origin;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {   
            // Create the new object where we want it to be.       
            TranslateOverTime mover = Instantiate(prefab, origin.position, origin.rotation);

            // Assign it a random velocity. Its script will move it from now on.
            mover.velocity = Random.onUnitSphere * moveSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```