# Moving a dynamically spawned object

Tags: unity, c#

I would like to create an object dynamically when the player presses <kbd>Q</kbd> and use this object in `Instantiate` and in `transform.Translate`.

The problem is that the translation must be outside the `if` that checks for the <kbd>Q</kbd> press, but it applies to the cube that I created inside the `if`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class instancier_new_object : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed=5f;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {
            GameObject objet = new GameObject ("objet");            
            GameObject cube = new GameObject ("cube");

            cube = Instantiate(
                       objet,
                       new Vector3(1, 2, 3),
                       Quaternion.identity
            );
        } 

        cube.transform.Translate(
                 Time.deltaTime*moveSpeed,
                 0,
                -Time.deltaTime*moveSpeed,
                 Space.Self
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the object outside of the `if` so that it moves even on frames when you're not pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>, then you need to store it in a member variable that can remember it between frames, from one invocation of `Update` to another.

While we're at it, we can also remove some redundant instantiation:

```
public class CreateObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    // Member variable to hold onto our spawned object.
    Transform _spawnedObject;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {          
            GameObject myObject = new GameObject("object");

            // Store the transform of the object to refer to it again later.
            _spawnedObject = myObject.transform;
            _spawnedObject.position = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
        } 

        // Check that we have a spawned object before trying to move it.
        if(_spawnedObject != null) {
            Vector3 step = new Vector3(1, 0, -1) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            _spawnedObject.Translate(step, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

This is very much the same as I've shown you in previous answers, so I encourage you to study them in more detail.

We can make this even cleaner though, by doing as I've recommended to you previously and *separating the spawning logic from the moving logic*.

Our movement logic can be very simple then:

```
public class TranslateOverTime : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, -1);

    void Update() {
        transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

And our spawner stays simple too:

```
public class CreateMovingObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {   
            // Create the new object where we want it to be.       
            GameObject myObject = new GameObject("object");
            myObject.transform.position = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);

            // Attach the movement behaviour to it, and configure its motion.
            var mover = myObject.AddComponent<TranslateOverTime>();
            mover.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, -1) * moveSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```